# PHP fgetcsv not getting correct number of rows

Tags: php, csv, fgets

I have a rather large csv file (17GB) which I'm trying to sanity check. I've written a little script which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$f = fopen($argv[1],'r');

$i=0;
while (!feof($f)) {
        $row = fgetcsv($f);
        $i++;
}
print $i."\n";

?>
```

Which should just read in the number of rows and print it out. This script outputs:
60770881

But if I do a `wc -l` the result is 60777200.

My csv file was generated from MySQL using:

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

So it shouldn't have any unescaped newlines or anything like that. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried grepping the file for lines that do match `^"` or `"$` as that would indicate an unescaped newline. I am not certain that \\ is the right way to escape newlines for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that, pointed the way to finding the problem, which was what Aleks G described

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV record can span multiple lines. If you have carriage-returns in any of the values, there will be multiple (2 or more) physical lines in the file (as counted by `wc`) but they would be read as one CSV record using `fgetcsv`.

Also, you don't need to check for `feof($f)`, because `fgetcsv` will return FALSE on end-of-file.